# Is this pure RDF or RDF Schema statement?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
             xmlns:contact="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/pim/contact#">

  <contact:Person rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/People/EM/contact#me">
    <contact:fullName>Eric Miller</contact:fullName>
    <contact:mailbox rdf:resource="mailto:em@w3.org"/>
    <contact:personalTitle>Dr.</contact:personalTitle> 
  </contact:Person>

</rdf:RDF>
```

In this example, is the document RDF schema or pure RDF? The RDF Primer document states that:

```
     "RDF itself provides no means for defining such application-specific 
classes and properties. Instead, such classes and properties are described 
as an RDF vocabulary, using extensions to RDF provided by RDF Schema... "
```

In above example, are the "Person" and "contact:fullName" etc are "application-specific classes and properties"? If that's the case, should RDF always be used together with RDF Schema?

Comment: Pure RDF is just relating entities with other entities or literals or blank nodes. Nothing more nothing less. But I don't understand why you'Re oping so many questions here, I don't get the problem. Why are you making things so complicated? Modeling a domain of interest is not that difficult, the only thing you have to think about is what should be an individual and what a class.

Comment: @AKSW, I am learning this stuff. Like the above example, when I see a namespace like "xmlns:contact#", such a namespace always represents a schema. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RDF/XML snippet serializes an RDF graph. The graph uses properties with the namespace http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/pim/contact#. Dereferencing the URI of the namespace will probably yield to a document serializing an RDF graph that uses the RDF schema vocabulary to describe the meaning of the properties in this namespace. Knowing the meaning of the properties used in your graph will allow you to understand what the RDF graph serialized by the above RDF/XML expresses.